# GITLAB CI where can I found logs from free runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Gitlab-runner for my "small" project.

From build logs, I am getting an error:

```
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app_face@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-10-10T07_34_49_432Z-debug.log
```

How can I access logs? Is it a remote machine? I didn't find any docs about this.

Answer (score 1):

The logs for the gitlab-runner service go to syslog or in case of systemd-based system also to: journalctl -u gitlab-runner.

If you are talking about gitlab.com runners, you do not have access to the machines, try using your own runner if needed.